# Why is my tableView not displaying objects?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, search, tableview

First of I would like to start with I am 100% new to iPhone development. I believe this is a quite simple question for someone experienced. Anyhow, what I am trying to do is:

The user should via the SearchUI be able to search for objects from my database. If the object exist, display it in the tableView where the search-objects will be displayed. I manage to get the objects from the database but not instance them into the tableview and display them.

Honestly I don't know what I am doing wrong. All help will be really appreciated and also some explaining if possible. Under method  `- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray *)objects` - I try to move the objects into the tableView without any success. You find the method in `FirstViewController.m` at the end of `pragma mark` TableView Data Scource methods. Here is my code:

FirstViewController.h class

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,           RKObjectLoaderDelegate>
{ 
UISearchDisplayController *searchDisplayController;
UISearchDisplayController *searchBar;
UITableView *table;
NSArray *allItems;
NSArray *searchResults;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISearchDisplayController     *searchDisplayController;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISearchDisplayController *searchBar;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITableView *table;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *allItems;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray *searchResults;
@end
```

FirstViewController.m class

```
#import "FirstViewController.h"
#import "Task.h"

interface FirstViewController ()

end

implementation FirstViewController

@synthesize searchDisplayController;
@synthesize searchBar;
@synthesize allItems;
@synthesize searchResults;
@synthesize table;

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
//self.listContent = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"John", @"Paul", nil];

//self.filteredListContent = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];

[super viewDidLoad];    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically  from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[super viewDidUnload];
// Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
else
{
    return YES;
}
}


-(BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller   shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
return NO;
}

- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller  shouldReloadTableForSearchScope:(NSInteger)searchOption
{
return NO;
}


- (void)searchBarSearchButtonClicked:(UISearchBar *)pSearchBar
{
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider setMapping:[Task getMapping]  forKeyPath:@"tasks"];

NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/%@", @"/book/1/tasks/", pSearchBar.text, @".json"];
[[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:path delegate:self];
NSLog(@"Search: %@", pSearchBar.text);  
}

#pragma mark - TableView Data Scource methods

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [self.searchResults count];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MyCell"];

if(cell == nil)
{
    cell =  [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault  reuseIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
}

cell.textLabel.text = [self.searchResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}

- (void) deselect { 
//[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]  animated:YES];
 }

// Respond to user selection tap by coloring the navigation bar
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)newIndexPath
{

}


- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray *)objects
{
self.searchResults = objects;

[self.table reloadData];


for(Task *task in objects)
{
    if ([task isKindOfClass:[Task class]])
    {
        NSLog(@"Loaded Book ID: %@ ; Name: %@ ; Book: %@", task.id, task.name,  task.book.name);  
    }
}

}

- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
NSLog(@"Encountered an error: %@", error);  
}
@end
```

Comment: check the self.searchResults array count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step1. Since your TableView is an IBOutlet, check you tableView datasource and delegate mappings in the .xib file for this view controller. My doubt is that the hooking is not correct.

Step2. If the hook ups in .xib file are correct, then you should do

```
- (void)objectLoader:(RKObjectLoader *)objectLoader didLoadObjects:(NSArray *)objects
{
   self.searchResults = objects;
   NSLog(@"%@", searchResults)
   [self.table reloadData];

....
}
```

and check if the NSLog is logging the searchResults array. If that's empty for some reason, your numberOfRowsInSection delegate method will return 0 and hence your tableView will be empty.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Or you can set delegate and dataSouce through your coding. Just try this code in your viewDidLoad method - self.table.delegate = self; self.table.dataSource = self;

Comment: Its not working..... Seems like dataSource/delegate is not the problem. I must have missed something basic in the code? Can tableView handle objects with 2 names? Or do I have to tell the tableView my objects have 2 names like Jesper and Martensson and not only Jesper ?

Comment: Try putting some NSLogs in the numberOfRowsInSection method to check that the data source is correctly setup. Also, I see that your object is not an NSString so you can't just set the cell's label to that object. First you have to take the text out of your object and then assign it to the cell's textLabel. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

in the first line

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,           RKObjectLoaderDelegate>
 { 
UISearchDisplayController *searchDisplayController;
UISearchDisplayController *searchBar;
UITableView *table;
NSArray *allItems;
NSArray *searchResults;
}
```

replace this line with below code

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, RKObjectLoaderDelegate>
 { 
UISearchDisplayController *searchDisplayController;
UISearchDisplayController *searchBar;
IBOutlet UITableView *table;
NSArray *allItems;
NSArray *searchResults;
}
```

and connect the tableview delegate and tableview datasource in interface builder.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Still not working.... Do you think it may be a problem that my objects has 2 items..? Like (item 1)Jesper (item 2)Martensson. Can it only display/accept 1 item? Something I have to think about?

Comment: You have to use NSMutableArray in place of NSArray. May be it will solve your problem.

Comment: You can display it as title and subtitle. Try setting cell.textLabel.text = yourObject.name (it is generic...adapt it to your own object)

Comment: Okay, I managed to get one step further... I can now display the objects in the TableView if I hit the cancel button and search once more. For more info look at my new post bellow...